# How do you access Matlab workspace from Matlab's GUI?

Tags: matlab

My workspace has a struct called 'output'
with 3 tables in it:

- Mid
- Def
- Forward

How do I access these 3 in my GUI code?

Comment: It's hard to answer, you should be more specific. Can you show us some code ? Is your structure `output` in the base workspace as the title suggests ?

Comment: @Ratbert, yes, the structure 'output' is in the base workspace, there isn't much code yet.

Comment: I won't write an answer based on so much information, but you should have a look at the function `evalin`, especially with someting like `evalin('base', 'output')` to acces the structure `output` from your GUI's workspace.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a structure array in the workspace called 'output' which contains various fields ('Mid','Def', etc). If you wish to access the field 'Mid', you can write output.Mid

Comment: Thank You @MadDave, but how do I access this in the GUI.m code?